# DROP VIEW without drop dependent views

Tags: sql, view, ibm-midrange, db2-400, drop

I need to change a VIEW, so I have to DROP and CREATE it.

DB2 manual say "Any views that are dependent on the view being dropped are made inoperative."

I try but dependent view are dropped, not made inoperative.

Is there a way to bypass the dependent views drop?

Comment: Perhaps you can do ALTER VIEW instead?

Comment: I can't use ALTER, because I need to change Join and Where conditions

Comment: I see. This is why its a good idea to have script that can re-create the whole environment if needed, or parts of it.

Comment: Ok, so the only way is using a Script... thank's a lot

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?  You have a `db2-400` tag, that platform offers `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` which should automatically recreate dependent views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sysibm.views` provides access to the `view_definition`

```
SELECT char(table_SCHEMA,10) libname,       
       char(table_NAME,30) view_name,       
       length(a.view_definition) lgth ,     
       cast(substr(a.view_definition,1,500) 
             as varchar(5000)) view_defn    
FROM   sysibm.views a
```

you should be able to first retrieve the definition of the dependent views. Then drop and recreate the view. And finally, create the dependent views from the saved view_definition.

Comment: A good start point